# electron-updater: Can not find module 'debug'

Tags: node.js, angular, sqlite, electron

I am developing Desktop App(windows/mac) using Electronjs. I was trying to implement auto-update feature using electron-updater since I am using electron-builder for the building.

I am able to generate .exe file for my app but when trying to install, it's throwing an error: "**Can not find module 'debug'**". Please find attached screenshot[image: Auto-updater-error].

Without electron-updater implementation, my app is running fine. When I am importing **autoUpdator** in my index.js, started getting that error. I am using autoUpdator as below:

```
const {autoUpdater} = require("electron-updater");
autoUpdater.on('update-downloaded', (ev, info) => {
  setTimeout(function() {
    autoUpdater.quitAndInstall();  
  }, 5000)
})
app.on('ready', ()=> {
  autoUpdater.checkForUpdates();
});
```

Please find the libraries description below:

- "electron-updater": "^4.0.6"
- "electron": "^3.0.6"
- "electron-builder": "^20.38.4"

I followed below links:

[Electron builder Auto Update](https://www.electron.build/auto-update)

[electron builder using local server](https://gist.github.com/iffy/0ff845e8e3f59dbe7eaf2bf24443f104)

I am new to the Electron js actively looking for your support.

As asked please find my build configuration below:

```
"build": {
    "appId": "com.****.*****",
    "productName": "********",
    "directories": {
      "output": "build"
    },
    "publish": [
      {
        "provider": "generic",
        "url": "http://127.0.0.1:4080/"
      }
    ],
    "nsis": {
      "oneClick": false,
      "perMachine": true,
      "allowElevation": true,
      "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory": true,
      "deleteAppDataOnUninstall": true,
      "createDesktopShortcut": true
    },
    "win": {
      "target": "nsis"
    },
    "files": [
      "!**/.vscode",
      "!**/build",
      "!**/config",
      "!**/assets/data",
      "!**/src"
    ],
    "extraResources": [
      {
        "from": "src/assets/data",
        "to": "dist/assets/data",
        "filter": "database*"
      }
    ]
  },
```

Comment: What happens when you run it in development mode? Does it throw any error there?

Comment: Can you share your configs for the build?

Comment: @RahulRaval, In development mode it runs fine. No error.

Comment: Try it without generating the .asar file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `"!**/src"` in your exclude list is the culprit.

1. Many node modules will have `"src"` folders which have to be packaged/bundled along with your application source code.
2. If you observe `"debug"` module folder under `"node_modules"` it has a `"src"` folder which has been excluded by above rule.

---

Suggestion: If you have your apps source folder as `"src"`, rename it to something else like `"source"` (which is in your control), but ensure you don't exclude `"src"` folders of `node_modules` (renaming these is not in your control as it could break the module's integrity and they get overwritten on fresh `npm install` also)